# A question about the equation describing the charging of a capacitor having a non-zero initial charge

Tags: capacitor

The equation describing the charging of a capacitor from a non-zero initial charge (connected in an LR circuit with a constant voltage source) is

$$q=VC[1-\frac{(EC-q_0)}{EC}e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}$$

However, the capacitor itself behaves as a fluctuating voltage source $$V=\frac{q(t)}{C}$$ which is discharging and being charged at the same time.

Why isn't that taken into account?

Comment: You can't discharge and charge capacitors or batteries at the same time. It's only ever going to be one or the other. This is because the capacitor has an "internal pressure" that resists being charged and tries to shove charge out of it. It's the same way you can't fill and empty a pressurized gas tank at the same time when it only has one port. You can't have the external voltage/pressure be be higher than the internal pressure to fill it while simultaneously also being lower than the internal pressure to empty it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...an LR circuit..

I suspect that a CR circuit is what is intended.

> Why isn't **[charging and discharging at the same time]** taken into account?

(The bold text is my interpretation.)

To answer this question, a complete circuit is required, so I expect that the circuit in Figure 1 is the one containing the capacitor on the question. The equation in the OP is incomplete and the terms not all defined so I will present using my notation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsXNlW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Kirchhoff's voltage law will present a differential equation that results in the following solution for the capacitor voltage \$v_{C}(t)\$ including initial conditions.
$$
v_{C}(t)=V_{A}\left(1-e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\right)+V_{0}e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\tag{equ 1}
$$

The term \$V_{A}\left(1-e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\right)\$ represents a charging of the capacitor, while the term \$V_{0}e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\$ represents a discharging of the capacitor.

It seems like the capacitor is both charging and discharging at the same time. It is an interesting way to understand the operation.

Actually the capacitor is charging if \$V_{A}>V_{0}\$ and discharging if \$V_{A}<V_{0}\$. Both charging an discharging are not happening at the same time, but the result is the same if it is viewed that way in the equation.

The equation can be manipulated into the form that most resembles the OP:
$$
v_{C}(t)=V_{A}+\left(V_{0}-V_{A}\right)e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\tag{equ 2}
$$

$$
v_{C}(t)C=V_{A}C\left[1+\frac{\left(V_{0}C-V_{A}C\right)}{V_{A}C}e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\right]
$$

$$
q(t)=v_{C}(t)C=V_{A}C\left[1+\frac{\left(Q_{0}-V_{A}C\right)}{V_{A}C}e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\right]\tag{equ 3}
$$

---

A comment about notation:
In the first equation (missing a closing bracket) the letter \$E\$ is not defined. The letter \$V\$ looks to be intended as the amplitude of the input step. Comparing with my solution (equ 3), V and E mean the same thing the amplitude of the input step, \$V_{A}\$.

Reusing \$V\$ in the second equation in the question as the voltage the capacitor is sourcing is incorrect. The voltage across the capacitor is always \$v_{C}(t)\$ (equ 1). So the second equation has no meaning.

Clarity of notation leads to clarity of the solution. It also allows answers to be meaningful. After looking at equ 1, the source of charging and discharging at the same time can lead to an interesting viewpoint, but the circuit diagram and correct, complete analysis allows good discussion leading to the correct interpretation based on \$\left(V_{0}-V_{A}\right)\$, (equ 2), being positive or negative as to whether the capacitor is charging or discharging